# DataGridView combobox column with datasource

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Have datagridview which contains 4 columns created manually from creator. 1st, 2nd and 3rd columns are just textbox columns but the last one is marked as comboboxcolumn.

User can add rows to it clicks on some button. Values for first three columns are comming from some textboxes. The problem is i have to populate combobx column when user add his row. What i tried so far was like this:

```
dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID, new Variation().GetAll())
```

Note that GetAll function retreiving datatable data inside are Id and Name. Id should be marked as value member and name as display member.

So simply saying user click some button on form tree first column's fields filling up from some textboxes, and last combobox column should be filled up by data from GetAll. How to achieve that?

---

```
   Private Sub btnAddMatType_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddMatType.Click

            try
              Dim dt as DataTable
              dt = New Variation().GetAll()


              Dim cbo = CType(dgvMaterials.Columns(3), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
              cbo.Items.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().Select(Function(s) s.Field(Of String)("Name")).ToArray())

              Dim rodzajID as String = TreeMaterials.SelectedValue
              Dim rodzajName as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Text
              Dim material as string = TreeMaterials.SelectedNode.Parent.Text

              dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID)


Catch ex As Exception
                msgbox(ex.ToString())
End Try
```

dt contains data:
[image]

grid look after all (no data in combo):
[image]

Drilling into cbo.Items:
[image]

Comment: a) Which thing is Nothing (hover the mouse)? It has to be `cbo` or `dt`.  Is there a cbo in the DGV design?  Did you set the name property to "Wariacja"?  Either of those would cause `cbo` to be null. b) **do not** pass the cbo in the `Rows.Add`, pass the value of that property if there is one.  Notice in mine that the first has a 4th data element item, the others do not.

Comment: @JimmyJimm Does this compile `Dim cbo As DataGridViewComboBoxColumn = Me.Wariacja`? (or whatever is the name of the ComboBoxColumn)

Comment: Note that it takes 2 clicks to open these things.  The first click is the row/cell being selected - you will see the row header arrow jump - the second opens the cbo

Comment: ...drill into `cbo.Items` - that is what you claim is empty

Comment: @Plutonix see main post for screenshoot

Comment: Did you see the "2 clicks" comment?  Thats true even when there is only one row.

Comment: @Plutonix what should i change then when i click button new row is added to grid but arrow header stays on previous one (not going to new one), then when i manualy click on new one arrow going to new one. Whats wrong in this?

Comment: when you click *what button*?  Your DGV is apparently `AllueUserToAddRows = False` so any new row being added has to be from your code.

Comment: @Plutonix there is button on form which his click event is associated with btnAddMatType_Click handler as you see in my code. User is not adding row directly in grid.

Comment: `dgvX.CurrentCell = dgvX.Rows(dgvX.Rows.Count - 1).Cells(0)`  as I said 2ce now, you dont want all that code in one click event.  You  will be adding copies of the cbo items list over and over

Answer (score 1):

If you created the columns yourself, you just need to add the cbo data.

```
Dim sql = "SELECT Id, Name FROM Foo"
Dim dt = ... get the dt from db

' cast column 3/Foo to CBO column to access CBO related props
Dim cbo = CType(dgv2.Columns("FooCol"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
cbo.DataSource = dt
cbo.ValueMember = "Id"
cbo.DisplayMember = "Name"
```

However, this will not work well without a `DataSource` like a `List` or `DataTable` for the DGV - there is no place to store the Id.  It would be simple to whip up a small class and a List for this, but it may also be overkill.

**Instead**, since you manually populate the DGV,  just populate the `Items` collection as well.This code sets up the list for the **entire column**, so it should be run once only:

```
Dim cbo = CType(dgv2.Columns("FooCol"), DataGridViewComboBoxColumn)
' get all the names to be used
cbo.Items.AddRange(dt.AsEnumerable().
                   Select(Function(s) s.Field(Of String)("Name")).
                   ToArray())
```

Adding rows simply involves adding a new row.  For the cbo column, you would pass a string indicating the current selection, or skip it maybe for a new row:

```
' add one or more rows - no Foo data yet
dgv2.Rows.Add("Ziggy", "Orange", 1, "Cat")
dgv2.Rows.Add("Zoey", "Blue", 3)
dgv2.Rows.Add("Zalgo", "Green", 78)
```

Note that populating the Items collection is a one-time thing.  You can add/remove rows as the user select things, but the cbo only needs to be set up once.

If there is data for foo - one of the values from the `DataTable` - supply it.  Unbound, you may need to hold onto the `DataTable` so you can look up the value/ID for the text selected.   Result:

[image][image]

---

Another alternative would be to copy the TreeView data to a class object and use a `PropertyGrid` if you are just editing one item at a time.  This would allow a `TypeConverter` to display one thing and save another as a data bound control would.

Comment: see main post agai i used by index now and now i get an error on this line: dgvMaterials.Rows.Add(material, rodzajName, rodzajID, "Farbe") says: In format of datagridview there was following exception: System.FormatException. Value od datagridviewcomboboxcell is not correct

Comment: Yup and it should.  Please read the answer carefully: the DGV is not bound so there is nowhere to store a ValueMember/Id which is why you need to use the `Items.AddRange` method.  Unless you want to wrap the data in a List<T>, apparently for one item, the user will pick an item, and you will look up the id.  Other than the DGV setup, [this is literally all the code I have to make it work](http://pastebin.com/qQV5Ar9J).  Use the datatable later to get the ID